# Java Spring Bean error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on "team table" with 3 columns `teamName` `teamManager` and `teamLead`. The `teamManager` and `teamLead` are 2 `int` type which will take values from a user table. I need to create a method that will save the 3 values and send them to the database

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveTeam", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getTeamList(final Model model,
            @ModelAttribute final Team team,
            @ModelAttribute("listTeams") final ArrayList<Team> teams, final Locale locale) {    

        final UserDto user =  (UserDto) model.asMap().get("loggedUser");
        try{
            final SaveTeamResponse response  =  teamService.saveTeam(team);
            if (!response.getServiceContext().getErrors().isEmpty()) {
                return ControllerUtils.errorsJson(response.getServiceContext().getErrors());
            } else {
                team.setId(response.getId());
                teams.add(team);
            }
        }catch (final SoapFaultClientException sfce) {
            logger.error("We sent an invalid message", sfce);
            model.addAttribute("error", "Validation error! We cannot process your subscription");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unexpected exception", e);
            model.addAttribute("error", "Server error! A unexpected error has occured");
        }

        return "team";
    }
```

The TeamService:

```
public interface TeamService {    

    public GetTeamResponse searchTeam(TeamCriteria criteria, String format , PaginationDto pagination, List<SortCriterionDto> sortCriteria);

    public boolean deleteTeam(List<Long> idTeam);    
    public void addUsersForTeams(String team, long id);    
    public SaveTeamResponse saveTeam(Team team);

    public List<ITeam>  searchTeams(Team teams);    
    public UpdateTeamResponse updateTeam(Team team);       
}
```

Html Table:

```
<table class="dataTable sortable" id="teamTable" >

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><div class="checkbox"></div></th>
                        <th class="column_teamName"><div class="narrow_field">
                                <div class="cellContent">
                                    <strong><spring:message code="label.teamName" /></strong>
                                </div>
                            </div></th>
                        <th class="column_teamManager"><div class="wide_field">
                                <div class="cellContent">
                                    <strong><spring:message code="label.teamManager" /></strong>
                                </div>
                            </div></th>
                        <th class="column_teamLead"><div class="wide_field">
                                <div class="cellContent">
                                    <strong><spring:message code="label.teamLead" /></strong>
                                </div>
                            </div></th>                         

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="teamTableBody" class="dataBody">
                    <c:forEach items="${listTeams}" var="team" varStatus="order">
                        <tr id="TeamRow${team.id}" data-order="${order.index}"
                            ondblclick="checkboxDblClickTeam(${team.id})">
                            <td><div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkedTeam${team.id}" name="toggle"
                                        onchange="checkboxClickTeam(${team.id})">
                                </div></td>

                            <td class="column_teamName" id="teamName${team.id}"><div
                                    class="narrow_field">
                                    <div class="cellContent">${team.teamName}</div>
                                </div></td>
                            <td class="column_teamManager" id="teamManager${team.id}"><div
                                    class="wide_field">
                                    <div class="cellContent">${team.teamManager.firstName} ${team.teamManager.lastName}</div>
                                </div></td>
                            <td class="column_teamLead" id="teamLead${team.id}"><div
                                    class="wide_field">
                                    <div class="cellContent">${team.teamLead.firstName} ${team.teamLead.lastName}</div>
                                </div></td>                             

                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Team Class:

```
public class Team  extends CrmEntity implements ITeam{

    private Long id;
    private String teamName;
    private IUserLogIn teamManager;
    private IUserLogIn teamLead;    

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }
    @Override
    public void setTeamName(final String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }
    @Override
    public IUserLogIn getTeamManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return teamManager;
    }
    @Override
    public void setTeamManager(final IUserLogIn teamManager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.teamManager = teamManager;
    }
    @Override
    public IUserLogIn getTeamLead() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return teamLead;
    }
    @Override
    public void setTeamLead(final IUserLogIn teamLead) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.teamLead =  teamLead;
    }
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'teamLead' of bean class [ro.axon.crm.model.Team]: Could not instantiate property type [ro.axon.crm.model.IUserLogIn] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: ro.axon.crm.model.IUserLogIn
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.newValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createDefaultPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:623)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setDefaultValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:611)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:917)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:750)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 53 more
```